# OpenLayers package installed?

Tags: openlayers, installation

I just downloaded the OpenLayers package but I think it returned an error or I didn't do it right. I have the snip attached. Does this mean that the OpenLayers package is installed or not?

[image: openlayers error message]

Answer (score 1):

It's installed but it's not the right way to do it

In `C:\Users\Owner`, you will find a directory node_modules with a child directory named `ol`.

Normally, what you do is

- create a directory with a meaningfull name for your project,
- cd into it
- run `npm init` and answer to the questions. It will create a file named `package.json`.
- do `npm install ol` and now it's fine

Your issue is in fact unrelated to OpenLayers `ol` package but to the fact your are not familiar at the moment with NPM/Node.js usage. You may look at doc section [Using NPM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/development_environment#using_npm) from MDN (Mozilla Developer Network)